# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string with varchar field as date

Tags: sql-server, date-conversion

I am trying to convert a MySQL query to SQL Server and this is as far as I have gotten. It appears SQL Server is unhappy with the fact that the table is storing DATE's (duedate in this case) as `VARCHAR`. So with that in mind, I tried converting them using CONVERT(DATE, EXPRESSION). Unfortunately I keep getting the "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error message. I'm not sure how else to attempt a conversion.

```
SELECT MYSQL_locationstesting.*, MYSQL_locations.sitenumb

FROM MYSQL_locationstesting 

INNER JOIN MYSQL_locations 
ON MYSQL_locationstesting.siteid=MYSQL_locations.id 

WHERE MYSQL_locationstesting.display = 1 
AND (CONVERT(DATE, MYSQL_locationstesting.duedate) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
AND MYSQL_locations.active = 1 
OR CONVERT(DATE, MYSQL_locationstesting.duedate) BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
AND DATEADD(DAY, 5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```

Comment: What year SQL Server edition?

Comment: What format is the date in? Is it one of the legal valid SQL Server date formats?

Comment: Jens - you removed the sql server tag when this is **obviously** SQL Server and NOT MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in SQL Server 2012, you have TRY_PARSE/CONVERT/CAST that can help. You are seeing that error because something is not able to be explicitly cast to a date type.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, 'This will break!')

SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE TRY_PARSE(your_column AS DATE) IS NULL
```

The 2nd query will return all your values that are unable to be cast to a date type. So you can add that to the bottom of your query to filter them all out:

```
AND TRY_PARSE(your_column AS DATE) IS NOT NULL
```

This will remove them from your results, so be careful with it if you want to still capture those values somehow.

Comment: Your 2nd query tagged onto my own did the trick! I will note though that the syntax as written didn't work. I had to do TRY_PARSE(column AS DATE). Otherwise, good to go, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have some data in the MySQL table that isn't a valid date value.

Use TRY_CONVERT() and supply whatever default value you want for the strings that can't be converted.